# gulp-expect-file is not working as expected on array of files

Tags: javascript, gulp

I have declared list of JS files for gulp task. On running gulp task it's giving error [tested : 5tests, failed: 5tests]. Please find below the code and error attachment.

```
var expect = require('gulp-expect-file');
var jsLibSources : [
        './bower_components/angular/angular.min.js',
        './bower_components/angular-animate/angular-animate.min.js',
        './bower_components/angular-bootstrap/ui-bootstrap.min.js',
        './bower_components/angular-bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls.min.js',
      ],

    gulp.task('jsLib', function() {
            return  gulp
                    .src(jsLibSources)
                    .pipe(expect(jsLibSources))
                    .pipe(concat('libraries.min.js'))
                    .pipe(gulp.dest(destLocation + 'js/'))
        });
```

[image]

Comment: It looks like those files might be missing. Have you run `bower install`?

Comment: yeah.. Moreover server is running fine. I added expect module for worst case to verify. But it seems not working.

Comment: Drop the `./` from your paths.

Comment: @SvenSchoenung Thanks!!!! It worked after removing ./ . But I don't understand why it was causing issue?